# Show that the p-Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $\phi$ is an automorphism of $G$ such that $\phi^3$ is the identity automorphism. Suppose further that $\phi(x) = x$ implies that $x = e$. Prove that for every prime $p$ which divides $o(G)$, the $p$-Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$.

Comment: @ Babak Miraftab : yes i am sure that $\phi(x) = x$ implies x = e

Comment: Are you familiar with frobenius action? If you are, just show that it is frobenius action then frobenius kernel $G$ is always nilpotent.

Comment: In fact the proof of nilpotency of groups admitting a fixed point free automorphism of order $3$, while not exactly easy, is a lot easier than the general result by Thompson for prime order fpf automorphisms. The $p=3$ case was done by Burnside, and is in his book.

Answer (score 2):

Definition: Let $A$ act on $G$ via Automorphisms.The action of $A$ on $G$ is said to be Frobenius if $ \phi(g)\neq g$ for every nonidendity $\phi\in A$ and $g\in G$.

Now, let $A=<\phi>$ then clearly $A$ acts on $G$ via Automorphisms.It is given that $\phi(g)\neq g$.Thus,we need to show that $\phi^2(g)\neq g$ for nonidendity $g\in G$.

Assume $\phi^2(g)= g\implies \phi^4(g)=\phi^2 (g) $ since $\phi^3=I$ $$\phi(g)=\phi^2(g)=g $$ contradiction.

so it is a Frobenius action which means that Frobenius kernel $G$ is nilpotent(Thompson theorem).Hence $G$ has normal Sylow-$p $subgroup.

http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/P.J.Flavell/research/publications/frobenius.pdf

Comment: @ mesel : I am not understanding  this notation $H^g$, Please tell me about this notation and thanks for helping me.

Comment: @user120386: $H^g=$ it is usually used for $g^{-1}Hg$.

Comment: @user120386: There are equivalent ways to define frobenius action.To see $A$ and $G$ in same group define semidirect product $R=G\rtimes A$ then equivalently you can say that $A\cap A^g=\{e\}$. instead of $\phi(g)\neq g$ for nontrivial $g\in G$.

Comment: @user120386: In that case $G\cong (R-\cup A^g)\cup \{e\}$

Comment: @user120386: If you want to learn these topics Finite group theory by I.Martin Isaacs is really a good source.You can read cheapter $3$ and $6$ in there. http://getebook.org/?p=270371

Comment: @ mesel : Thanks

Comment: @user120386: you are welcome.